# How to app switch when guided access is enabled

Tags: ios, ipad, guided-access

I am building an app for kiosk usage and we're very happily using guided access mode. However, there is indeed a suite of apps and until recently, we were using URL scheme switching to switch between different apps. However, we found out that guided access doesn't allow URL switching.

Any suggestions?

(We want to keep apps separate for brevity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard back from Apple that this is not possible